# How to disable slide range when checked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How to disable slide range when checked `checkbox` ?

When checked checkbox `id="unlimited"` I want to disable slide range

```
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "disable" ) );
```

but when not checked checkbox `id="unlimited"` i want enable slide range

```
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

I test this code but not work, How can i do that ?

### **[FIND FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/b63u9krv/4/)**

---

### **SCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
range: "min",
value: 0,
min: 0,
max: 700,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
}
});      
if (document.getElementById('unlimited').checked) 
    {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "disable" ) );
    } 
else 
    {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
    }

});
```

Comment: You don't use jQuery in your fiddle and you must use click event on #unlimited, I edited your fiddle to working example: http://jsfiddle.net/b63u9krv/8/

Answer (score 3):

To disable JqueryUi Slider, you should use **option disabled** property to set it. Also you need to grab the event of check box to set the slider disable and enable ability.

Just put the bellow code, this will set property as your expected behavior. You can see this in [**http://jsfiddle.net/b63u9krv/10/**](http://jsfiddle.net/b63u9krv/10/) and also like bellow:

```
$(function() { 
  $("#slider-range-min" ).slider({
     range: "min",
     value: 0,
     min: 0,
     max: 700,
     slide: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
            }
  });

  // Grab the click event of check box.
  $( "#unlimited" ).click(function(){
   if(this.checked)
     {  
       // set the slider as disable
       $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "option", "disabled", true );
     } 
   else 
     {
       // set the slider as enable again when you click to uncheck
      $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "option", "disabled", false );
     } 
  });    
});
```

Comment: Whay are you mixing jQuery and plane javascript? 'getElementById'? You already selected #unlimited, just use 'this' in your click function. It's that checkbox, no need for document.getElementById just if(this.checked) { ... }

Comment: @freshbm i just updated to code to work as the expectation of akser! If he want to use only js or jquery then it is easier now after knowing his missing point. Anyway i am editing it to use only jquery. is this okey?

Comment: Ok, now is better, but you can just write: this.checked instead: $(this).is(':checked') == true. Cheers